# Get a string after a certain substring

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I get a string after a certain substring:

```
strings = ["Mayo", "Nice May", "nice May comes", "nice Mayo", "nice Mayo comes"]
substring = "May"
```

I want to get only the strings that **have the word "May" in it** and **not just contain the sequence "May"**.

I have tried these codes:

```
for x in strings:
    if "May" in x:
        print(x)
```

```
for x in strings:
    if x.find("May"):
        print(x)
```

I want:

```
Nice May                                                                                                                       

nice May comes
```

I get:

```
Mayo                                                                                                                               
Nice May                                                                                                                           
nice May comes                                                                                                                     
nice Mayo                                                                                                                          
nice Mayo comes                                                                                                                    
abcMayabc
```

Comment: Hint: what are words usually separated by?

Comment: hi @all, please guide him but not do it for him

Answer (score 1):

Using `split()`, check if `substring` is `in` the `elem` of `strings` separated by spaces:

```
strings = ["Mayo", "Nice May", "nice May comes", "nice Mayo", "nice Mayo comes"]
substring = "May"

for x in strings:
    if substring in x.split(" "): print(x)
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
Nice May
nice May comes
```

Using `list comprehension`:

```
print([x for x in strings if substring in x.split()])
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
['Nice May', 'nice May comes']
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Regex boundaries.

**Ex:**

```
import re

strings = ["Mayo", "Nice May", "nice May comes", "nice Mayo", "nice Mayo comes"]
substring = "May"

for i in strings:
    if re.search(r"\b{}\b".format(substring), i):
        print(i)
```

**Output:**

```
Nice May
nice May comes
```